# How to define new icons with winjs commands?

Tags: winjs

How to use an **icon** which is not provided by WinJS? For example, use [one](http://modernicons.io/segoe-mdl2/cheatsheet/) from here.

The html looks like:

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" data-win-options="{ label: 'Home', icon: 'home'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The png image should be 20x20 pixels with a transparent background (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700483.aspx). The png is set as in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("thatFancyButton").style.backgroundImage = url('pathOfPNGImage');
```

so in your case it is (notice \' \' in url()):

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" data-win-options="{ label: 'Home', icon: 'url(\'pathOfPng.png\')'}"></div>
```

You can also set one letter glyphs like icon: '©' and it will show it as icon.

Below is the snippet of the SplitViewCommand icon setting logic:

```
            /// <field type="String" locid="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand.icon" helpKeyword="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand.icon">
            /// Gets or sets the icon of the SplitViewCommand. This value is either one of the values of the AppBarIcon enumeration or the path of a custom PNG file.
            /// </field>
            icon: {
                get: function () {
                    return this._icon;
                },
                set: function (value) {
                    this._icon = (_Icon[value] || value);

                    // If the icon's a single character, presume a glyph
                    if (this._icon && this._icon.length === 1) {
                        // Set the glyph
                        this._imageSpan.textContent = this._icon;
                        this._imageSpan.style.backgroundImage = "";
                        this._imageSpan.style.msHighContrastAdjust = "";
                        this._imageSpan.style.display = "";
                    } else if (this._icon && this._icon.length > 1) {
                        // Must be an image, set that
                        this._imageSpan.textContent = "";
                        this._imageSpan.style.backgroundImage = this._icon;
                        this._imageSpan.style.msHighContrastAdjust = "none";
                        this._imageSpan.style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        this._imageSpan.textContent = "";
                        this._imageSpan.style.backgroundImage = "";
                        this._imageSpan.style.msHighContrastAdjust = "";
                        this._imageSpan.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            },
```

If you happen to have errors with the background image size, modify win-commandimage class. I did this fix in styles to fit the image into button correctly:

```
.win-commandimage {
    background-size:contain;
}
```